# ¿Cómo concatenar query inner join?

Tags: php, sql, servidor, while

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta diciéndole que me traiga un resultado por un id `(vin='".$rw["vin"]."')` traído de otra consulta y generado por un `while` de la siguiente manera; pero no concatena correctamente el resto del query después de la variable php. Sé que me falta alguna comilla o punto, el caso es que no esta bien concatenado:

```
$dif3="SELECT * From v_ivh_siembras_comercial_tabla where tipo_factura='FVNV' AND fecha_evento_entrega BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-08-01' ORDER BY fecha_evento_entrega asc";

//EJECUCIÓN DE LA CONSULTA
$dif3 = odbc_exec($condms,$dif3);
if (odbc_num_rows($dif3)!=0){

  while($rw = odbc_fetch_array($dif3)) 
  {     
     echo "<td>".$rw['vin']."</td>"."<td>".$rw['kilometraje']."</td>";

     $sql="SELECT v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla.vin, v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla.kilometraje,* 
FROM v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla
INNER JOIN (

SELECT MAX( kilometraje ) kilometraje, vin
FROM v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla where ***vin='".$rw["vin"]."'***
GROUP BY vin
)t1 ON t1.vin = v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla.vin
AND t1.kilometraje = v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla.kilometraje
ORDER BY v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla.kilometraje DESC";
```

Comment: Imagino que los asteriscos son para señalar que tienes problemas ahí !!!!. Construyes tus consultas usando una **pésima práctica**, 1º porque estás escribiendo un código totalmente vulnerable a la Inyección SQL, pasando en la consulta de forma directa, datos que provienen desde fuera. 2º. Si de todos modos quieres escribir la consulta de esa forma **vulnerable**, guarda `$rw["vin"]` en una variable y luego concaténala en la variable `$sql`. El problema es que al comenzar la variable `$sql` por comillas dobles `"` y al usar comillas dobles en `$rw["vin"]` estás teniendo un lío de comillas...

Comment: Y... ¿esto aquí, que es: **`... v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla.kilometraje >> ,* FROM <<  v_ivh_siembras_posventa_tabla...`**? Nunca había visto: `nombre-columna, coma, asterisco, FROM`

Comment: podrías añadir el valor de sql despues de intentar concatenar? por otro lado usar * no es una buena practica, es mejor poner el nombre de las columnas